# Redirecting one folder's contents to another without symlink

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I have been given 2 public facing folders for personal use by my sysadmin, one for HTTP and the other for HTTPS. For a variety of reasons, I would prefer users to be auto-redirected to the HTTPS site if they try to visit the HTTP site. Yet, the sysadmin has set it up so that any HTTP connections will search for the HTTP folder, and if it does not exist, show a "file does not exist 404 error".

I contacted the sysadmin, who recommended using a symlink to ensure I don't have to manually update both folders, yet this does not solve my problem and still allows people to access through HTTPS. How can I ensure users get auto-redirected without manually writing auto-redirects for every single file?